# Control flow of PHP scripts

Tags: php, methodology

I have a PHP script **example1.php**.

How would the control flow be when I call another PHP script **example2.php** from **example1.php**?

For e.g.:

```
 example1.php looks like this
 ....
 ...
 ....
 example2.php (calling example2.php from example1.php)
 .....
 .....
```

How does the control flow work for this? Does **example1.php** wait until **example2.php** completes execution and then continuous with rest of code logic or does it just continues allowing **example2.php** to run independently?

Comment: Yes, the control flow is sequential (ie, it waits for one to finish before moving on). But using php files like that will cause an awful mess.

Comment: How should I use it then ?

Comment: @run_rookie Your best bet is to use an existing framework which does a lot of the architecture for you.

Answer (score 4):

The parsing is done line by line in php.

So it will go sequentially.

Yes example1.php will wait until it completes execution of example2.php